# put it up - put it out: what does it mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I don't really understand the meaning of "put it up" and "put it out" in this context. The context is work in a professional kitchen: a chef is explaining to a cook how to prepare a dish:

«I know that dish takes 5 minutes and it’s only been 2; **don’t even put it up**. I’d rather you take an extra minute [and] slow up service to get it right. But **don’t put it out**, because that 1 minute you save **in putting it out** is going to become 6 minutes behind because you’re going to have to redo the plate.»

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Regard the shelf in the picture below:

[image]

That shelf is where chefs put food so that the waiting staff can take it out to the customers. Once the food is on that shelf, the waiting staff assume it is ready to be served.

When the speaker is talking about *putting the food up*, I believe they are talking about putting the dish 'up' on that shelf so that the waiting staff can take it out of the kitchen and into the restaurant. When the speaker talks about *putting the food out* they are talking about the chef sending the food into the restaurant to the customer.

<sup>Image reference: [TVGuide.com](http://www.tvguide.com/news/kitchen-nightmares-ending-1083309/) accessed 04/04/2017</sup>

Comment: And that shelf is called 'the pass', I believe.

Comment: @Spagirl I knew there had to be a word for that. I worked in restaurants loads when I was younger, but I never heard any special word for it!